# How to add type converter using Room?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room to save data in SQLite. But, i get error type converter.

I've data class like :

```
@Entity(tableName = FavoriteDatabase.teamTable)
data class TeamItem(
    @SerializedName("idAPIfootball")
    val idAPIfootball: Any?,
    @SerializedName("idLeague")
    val idLeague: String?,
    @SerializedName("idSoccerXML")
    val idSoccerXML: String?,
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("idTeam")
    val idTeam: String,
    @SerializedName("intFormedYear")
    val intFormedYear: String?
}
```

I get error :

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private final java.lang.Object idAPIfootball = null;
```

I try add Converter :

```
object Converter {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toString(data: Any): String = data.toString()

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toAny(data: String): Any = data
}
```

and Add in RoomDatabase :

```
@Database(entities = [TeamItem::class, EventItem::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converter::class)
abstract class FavoriteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
}
```

and I get error :

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at id.afdaldev.footballmatchscheduleapp.data.model.Converter.toString(Unknown Source:2)
```

Comment: solved.
`object Converter {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toString(data: Any?): String? {
        return data?.toString()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun toAny(data: String?): Any? = data
}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for the converter

```
 @TypeConverter
    fun fromAnyToString(value: Any?): String? {
        return if (value == null) null else String(value)
    }
```